How to Save URI returned from ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT and Use In Different Activity/Fragment
How do I save the URI returned from Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT and then use this URI to be used in a different Activity or Fragment? Since startActivityForResult is deprecated, I'm incredibly lost.
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
           type = "application/pdf"
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent)



Create variable of ActivityLauncher.

Initialize the launcher in Oncreate()

Then call above method with launch(what you have written above that code).

Also I created a Constants.kt file with a companion object to save uri.
private lateinit var createTxtLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)


    createTxtLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){result ->

        if(result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            val uri: Uri? = result.data?.data
           Constants.uri  = uri.toString()
        }

    }

    binding.saveButtonId.setOnClickListener {

        createAndSaveFile()
    }


    }

private fun createAndSaveFile(){
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        setType("text/plain")
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "chinmay.txt")
    }
    createTxtLauncher.launch(intent)
}



Constants.kt file
     class Constants {
     companion object {
         var uri: String = ""
     }
}


Thanks, this works... kind of. It's storing the uri, but not as expected.  content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A1000013540 - And when I try to retrieve the file via the uri, I get a "File Does Not Exist" error. Any ideas why?
